# PHP, OOP, Static

Tags: php, oop, static

I am have a problem with undestanding some sentence at PHP.net about the static keyword,
At This [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php), PHP.net Explaining about the static keyword i did understand all they say but i didn't succeed to get one sentence witch start at "Like any other PHP static variable".
I just didn't get it if can some one please help me with code example, mabye explanation will be great.

Comment: Thank You Guy's i am reading now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When saying "like any other static variable" the manual refers to a static variable inside a function. The archetypal example is the function that keeps an internal counter:

```
function foo() {
    static $counter = 0; // static variable
    return ++$counter;
}
```

Static variables like this and static class properties both have a limitation on the expressions you can initialize them with.

```
function foo() {
    static $counter = getInitialValue(); // ERROR: not possible!
    return ++$counter;
}
```

If you need to do something like this, the usual workaround is

```
function foo() {
    static $counter; // not initialized explicitly, same as = null
    if ($counter === null) { // three equals!
        $counter = getInitialValue();
    }
    return ++$counter;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer i understand it if you can please explain what was happen if you were using two equals, i know the Difference between two to three but can you explain the difference please at this case.

Comment: @Blanktext: There is no special difference in this case. I 'm just avoiding situations where `$counter` would be initialized to e.g. `0`, we wouldn't want to reset it every time.

Comment: Thank you Very Much Jon, i understand it all now, Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can do this:

```
class Foo
{
    public static $my_static = 'foo';

    public function staticValue() {
        return self::$my_static;
    }
}
```

where `$my_static` is initialise as a string with the value `foo`. But you can't do:

```
class Foo
{
    public static $my_static = substr('food',0,3);

    public function staticValue() {
        return self::$my_static;
    }
}
```

and expect `$my_static` to contain the results of the function call to `substr`; directly assigning a function's return value to a static variable is an illegal operation. Similarly, you can't do:

```
class Foo
{
    public static $my_static = 'foo';
    public static $my_static_2 = $my_static;

    public function staticValue() {
        return self::$my_static;
    }
}
```

because you may not initialise a static variable by pointing to another variable.